# There has been a critical error on this website

Tags: wordpress

This Error Showing Whem I am Going To Login Into My Wordpress Site
Wordpress Version 5.7.2

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Elementor\TemplateLibrary\Source_Base' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\template-library\sources\local.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\autoloader.php(294): require() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\autoloader.php(330): Elementor\Autoloader::load_class('TemplateLibrary...') #2 [internal function]: Elementor\Autoloader::autoload('Elementor\Templ...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\modules\library\documents\not-supported.php(38): spl_autoload_call('Elementor\Templ...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\base\document.php(175): Elementor\Modules\Library\Documents\Not_Supported::get_properties() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\core\documents-manager.php(148): Elementor\Core\Base\Document::get_property('cpt') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\modules\libra in C:\xampp\htdocs\Ecommarce\wp-content\plugins\elementor\includes\template-library\sources\local.php on line 24

Answer (score 1):

Normally when I encounter "There has been a critical error on this website", a hard refresh helps (shift + F5). Otherwise some of your plugins might be having conflict. I would start with disabling plugins one by one and seeing if any of them are what's causing the issue.

In my experience either of these solutions have always worked.